# What is causing my AC to trip the breaker after running for about an hour?

Tags: central-air

After I turn on my ac, about an hour or two later it will make  a noise and trip the breaker. Could this be a short in my fan motor? The fan does run.

Comment: What makes a noise, and what does the noise sound like?  Is the A/C running nonstop for the whole hour?  Is the temperature in the house going down? When was the last time you cleaned/changed the filter? When was the last time you cleaned the condenser?

Answer (score 1):

If the a/c runs for the better part of an hour, it is almost certainly not a short circuit.

More likely, the air conditioner is slightly overloading the circuit.  Or possibly the circuit breaker has "derated itself."  Fix the latter by replacing the circuit breaker.

**Always** choose a replacement circuit breaker based on the wire capacity, not the devices connected.  For example, replacing an appropriately sized 20 amp breaker with a 30 amp could easily start a fire from inside the walls.

Addendum:  see the time-to-trip for a line of GE circuit breakers [here](http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/GES-9884?TNR=Time%20Current%20Curves%7CGES-9884%7Cgeneric).  Note that it is normal for slightly overloaded breakers to take hours to trip.